# I edited an "on hold" question but it is still closed

Tags: support, editing, closing, closed-questions

I edited [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2358959/93201) today to provide some context for things I've tried but it was still closed. Is this because the original poster posed the question too simply or is it still in a state to be considered off topic? I'm very new to posing questions on this SE site and the other questions about on or off topic questions don't seem to rule this question out as off topic.

Comment: Was this downvoted because there are other questions about this? I really do want to be a good citizen here, but have seen a lot of downvoting that I really don't understand.

Comment: Downvoting on the main site is unpredictable. On Meta, voting doesn't affect reputation at all so the voting is even less predictable. It could be anything: they think your title is bad, they think you should have done more research, they just stubbed their big toe and are taking it out on you.

Comment: The Question linked above is now reopened.  Note that there is a dedicated thread here on Meta ([Requests for Reopen & Undeletion Votes, etc.](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19042/requests-for-reopen-undeletion-votes-etc-volume-01-2015-current-versio)) for "pleading the case" when the normal course of review has failed.  In general I would give it a full day after making the kind of edit you describe before asking the Community to pay special attention.

Comment: @hardmath that's good advice. I only asked because it went from "on hold" to "closed" only shortly after I had edited it and was not sure if the proper etiquette was to plead the case or ask the question again with more context.

Comment: The transition (from on-hold to closed) was simply a matter of time passing.  I applaud your effort to make the Question suitable for answering.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If a question which is on hold is edited, then the edit pushes it into reopen review queue, assuming some conditions are fulfilled. Details can be found in [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16820#16821) on our meta and [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/256567#256572) on meta.SO. Probably the main things are:

- This only happens if the question has been on-hold/closed for no longer than *five days.*
- A question can be enqueued via editing *only once* per closure. (So it is better to make substantial edits which address all issues which may be among reasons why the question was put on hold.

In the review, users with sufficient reputation can vote whether the question should remain closed or be reopened. After the review is finished, you can see it on the [timeline](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/timeline/info) of the post.

In this specific case you can see [on the timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2358959/timeline) the question indeed [got into reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/843346) where some users voted to reopen and some users voted to leave closed.

Answer (score 4):

Editing the question does not reopen it. Closing and reopening a question is done by a voting process. Users with at least 3000 reputation may [cast close and reopen votes](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/close-questions). It takes 5 votes to close a question and another 5 to reopen it. Users with at least 15 but less than 2999 reputation may [raise flags](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/flag-posts) to close a question but not to reopen it.

See also [What if I disagree with the closure of a question? How can I reopen it?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/reopen-questions) and [What does it mean if a question is "closed" or "on hold"?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions).

At the time of writing this answer there are 3 votes to reopen the question.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! I really appreciate the explanation of the voting process!

Comment: T.Gunn (and @jcaudle): It is true edit editing *does not reopen* the question, but still it puts the question *into reopen review queue.* (When some additional conditions are fulfilled, the most important is probably that it is at most 5 days since the question was put on hold. For details see [this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/16820#16821).) As you can see on the [timeline](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/2358959/timeline) of the question, the question [was indeed reviewed](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/843346).