# How should I improve my question?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, asking-questions, on-hold-questions

I have a question about my Mathematics Stack Exchange post: [Trouble with complex numbers within a given equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3324352/trouble-with-complex-numbers-within-a-given-equation)

Two things

$1.~$ Is their anyway I can get this question off the "On hold" status ?

I made edits to this question and I have provided more information than I needed to satisfy comments that were posted bellow.

$2.~$ Can someone add a button to questions that raise a flag when the question is "On hold" to signal to moderators or someone that the author of said question had felt like they had made adequate edits to the question ?

How do I get someone to view my question?

Comment: To solve some equation, one needs to know what are the knowns and unknowns. I think it unclear in your post. Also, the quotient that has the sine function is an "expression", not an "equation".

Comment: Re: "How do I get someone to view my question?" The first edit after the question is put on hold moves your question in [reopen review queue](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/reopen/1238406). You can find more details [in this answer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/16820/should-i-avoid-minor-edit-of-a-question-which-was-put-on-hold/16821#16821).

Answer (score 0):

Besides some inefficient use of **MathJax** or uninteresting view of your question, for those who are new to your question (even me in this case), some ambiguities may arise:

1. What is a **Miller type integrator**?
2. What do the variables in you question stand for? and which subfield of mathematics are you pursuing?
3. As you said, a simple graph cannot be plotted since of $j=\sqrt {-1}$. So which charts make you satisfy instead? Real-part plot? Imaginary-part plot? Absolute value plot? Angle plot?
4. In $E_2=-\frac{sin⁡(X*ω)}{jωR_1 C_1 },   X=time\space  or\space  the\space  X\space  axis\space  on\space a\space  graph$ you could have used \text{time or the X axis on a graph}
5. In MSE, you must be looking for outlines instead of full answers. For example, if you are trying to plot a function $f(x)={\sin ax\over bx+c}$ where $a,b,c$ can be complex numbers, you can constrain the definition scope of them to e.g. real numbers.

If you edit your question, a notification will be sent to all those who have participated in actions related with your question. If they see the edits fulfilling the minimum thresholds of a standard question, they will vote to reopen, unless you can delete your old question, and ask a new one with better points of view.

Comment: "If you edit your question, a notification will be sent to all those who have participated in actions related with your question." I don't think that's true. By the way, Mostafa, did you notice that Ben's question on main was reopened after he posted here, then closed a second time when voters found the question was still unclear? Did you notice the comments I made, with which neither you nor Ben has engaged?

Comment: "If you edit your ..." why not? Besides, if trying to persuade the people who downvoted the question to nominate it for reopening, the owner of the question should make sure to have added enough details such that the question statement is clear and simple. I did not notice the Ben's case as it is justifiable that a question even reopened once more, gets closed for a second time for the same reason of the first time since the voters did not determine the edits as enough. Also, I did not make any comments or contributions to the question in main, and I did not receive any notification.

Comment: "If you edit your question..." was a quote from the last paragraph of your post. I just don't think it's true that if the poster edits a closed question then everybody who took part in the question gets notified.